# Connect to RDS through peering connection across private VPC

Tags: networking

This is my situation:

- RDS in VPC-A and AWS-account-A
- Server1 in VPC-B, AWS-account-B and is private network only
- Server2 in VPC-B, AWS-account-B and is on public network (eth0) and private network (eth1)

the private network subnet is 172.31.0.0/20

the public network subnet is 172.31.100.0/24

I have managed to set peering connection between VPC-A network (172.41.0.0/20) and the private network of  VPC-B. I checked and I can connect from Server1 to the RDS successfully.

There is a network connection between Server1 and Server2 works. Basically Server2 has two network interfaces, and eth1 is on the private network.

My problem is that I can't get it to work from Server2, for some reason there is a networking problem.

from Server2 (I added route for the RDS network:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.32.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.31.32.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.31.100.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
172.41.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
```

but traceroute shows it is not reachable:

```
$ traceroute 172.41.32.14
traceroute to 172.41.32.14 (172.41.32.14), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  ip-172-31-100-102.us-west-2.compute.internal (172.31.100.87)  2998.396 ms !H  2998.376 ms !H  2998.372 ms !H
```

but:

```
$ ping 172.31.100.87
PING 172.31.100.87 (172.31.100.87) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.31.100.87: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.351 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.100.87: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.365 ms
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it

In AWS console, VPC->Subnets, I located the subnet of the public network, and then below in the "Route Table" I added:

```
172.41.0.0/16 => peer connection
```

After I did this, and removed the route that I created in Server2, it started working.